# numpy distutils -- Try to compile something and set flags if you fail

Tags: python, numpy, distutils

One common way to build source code on *NIX platforms is to use a `configure` script.  Under the hood, configure tries to build a bunch of test programs to determine which libraries you have accessible.  It then generates a header file which gets included in the project that defines a bunch of macros conditionally so that the programmer can supply an alternative or build a stripped down version of a library/program if a particular "dependency" is missing.  Is there anything functionally equivalent using `numpy.distutils`?

As an example, here is my `setup.py`:

```
from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration

def configuration(parent_package='',top_path=None):
    config = Configuration('pyggcm',parent_package,top_path)

    #TODO: Currently, I have some macros to conditionally build the seek-code
    #Unfortunately, that's not the best solution (by far).  Perhaps if we
    #changed to using stream access it would work better, without the need
    #for these silly macros.
    config.add_extension('_fortfile',sources=['_fortfile/_fortfile.F90'],
                         define_macros=[
                             ('FSEEKABLE',1),  #compiler provides fseek and ftell
                             ('HAVE_STREAM',1) #compiler provides access='stream' for opening files. (f2003 standard)
                             ])  

    config.add_extension('jrrle',sources=['jrrle/jrrle.f90'])
    config.add_scripts(['scripts/ggcm_timehist',
                        'scripts/ggcm_plasmasheet',
                        'scripts/ggcm_plot'])
    return config


from numpy.distutils.core import setup    
setup(configuration=configuration)
```

This is unconditionally building the `FSEEKABLE` code and would need to be manually edited if the users Fortran compiler doesn't support that (The macros wrap the `fseek` and `ftell` GNU intrinsic function).  Is there a way to determine whether the Fortran compiler supplies those intrinsic functions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import os
import shutil
import tempfile
from distutils.ccompiler import new_compiler

def hasfunction(cc, funcname, include=None, extra_postargs=None):
    tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix='hasfunction-')
    devnull = oldstderr = None
    try:
        try:
            fname = os.path.join(tmpdir, 'funcname.c')
            f = open(fname, 'w')
            if include is not None:
                f.write('#include %s\n' % include)
            f.write('int main(void) {\n')
            f.write('    %s;\n' % funcname)
            f.write('}\n')
            f.close()
            devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
            oldstderr = os.dup(sys.stderr.fileno())
            os.dup2(devnull.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())
            objects = cc.compile([fname], output_dir=tmpdir,
                                 extra_postargs=extra_postargs)
            cc.link_executable(objects, os.path.join(tmpdir, 'a.out'))
        except Exception as e:
            return False
        return True
    finally:
        if oldstderr is not None:
            os.dup2(oldstderr, sys.stderr.fileno())
        if devnull is not None:
            devnull.close()
        shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)
```

Example:

```
def detect_sse3():
    "Does this compiler support SSE3 intrinsics?"
    compiler = new_compiler()
    return hasfunction(compiler, '__m128 v; _mm_hadd_ps(v,v)',
                       include='<pmmintrin.h>',
                       extra_postargs=['-msse3'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a code fragment into a file & try to compile it checking the error codes is the normal approach and should work nicely - however AFAIK nobody has already done this for you as a part of distutils.  I suspect that one of the other, possibly python based, build tools such as may support this.  I think that your best bet is GNU autoconfigure.

Comment: Missing word: *...build tools such as may...*?